# Duplicados en un DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

1.- Tengo un data frame con tres columnas: ARCHIVO, ID_ANIMAL y ANIMAL:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ARCHIVO': ['fuente1','fuente1','fuente1','fuente1','fuente1', 'fuente2','fuente2'], 'ID_ANIMAL': ['001', '001', '001', '002', '003','004','004'], 'ANIMAL': ['Abeja', 'Abeja', 'Abeja', 'Ballena', 'Camaron','Dromedario','Dromedario']})
df
```

Este Data Frame tiene elementos repetidos, por lo cual quiero lograr mostrar en otro DataFame, el número de registros duplicados por archivo:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'ARCHIVO':df['ARCHIVO'].unique(),'DUPLICADOS':'NaN'})
df_1
```

2.- La salida que quisiera obtener es en el `df_1` en lugar de 'NaN' me aparezca el número de duplidados de ese archivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que se me ocurre para resolver este problema es utilizar [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) con [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) y **`keep = False`** o bien dejar keep en `'first'` (si quieres que **n-1** filas para cada archivo para las cuales existen una fila idéntica sea el número de duplicados y no **n** (`keep = False`) ) para que la Serie booleana que se genera tenga True en todos los valores duplicados para cada archivo y después sumar por nivel aprovechando la Serie con `MultiIndex`.

### **Método 1**

```
df_1 = (df.groupby(['ARCHIVO'])
          .apply(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep = False))
          .sum(level=0)
          .rename('DUPLICADOS')
          .reset_index())
print(df_1)
   ARCHIVO  DUPLICADOS
0  fuente1         3.0
1  fuente2         2.0
```

---

### Método 2

Sin embargo el uso de `apply` [`suele ser desaconsejado`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code). Puede ser evitado aquí de algunas de las siguientes maneras.

```
df_1 =(df.duplicated(keep=False)  
         .groupby(df['ARCHIVO'])
         .sum()
         .rename('DUPLICADOS')
         .reset_index())
print(df_1)
   ARCHIVO  DUPLICADOS
0  fuente1         3.0
1  fuente2         2.0
```

### Método 3

O bien realizar una [`indexación booleana`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) para quedarnos con un DataFrame de duplicados y entonces calcular el tamaño con [`groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html)

```
(df[df.duplicated(keep = False)].groupby('ARCHIVO')
                                .size()
                                .rename('DUPLICADOS')
                                .reset_index() )
```

### Método 4

Tambien en este último caso podríamos utilizar [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

```
(df.loc[df.duplicated(keep = False),'ARCHIVO']
   .value_counts()
   .rename('DUPLICADOS')
   .rename_axis(index = 'ARCHIVO')
   .reset_index())
```

¿Qué método elegir?, normalmente `value_counts` suele ser mas rápido que utilizar `groupby` para marcos de datos **muy grandes**. Puedes experimentar para ver cual es el más rápido para ti. Sim embargo, creo que el mejor método sera el **método 2**, ya que no tenemos que realizar la indexación boolean y la función suma de una Series es muy rápida. Creo que este método funcionara bien sea cual sea las dimensiones de tu marco de datos.

```
%%timeit
(df.loc[df.duplicated(keep = False),'ARCHIVO']
   .value_counts()
   .rename('DUPLICADOS')
   .rename_axis(index = 'ARCHIVO')
   .reset_index())
4.31 ms ± 691 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
df_1 = (df.groupby(['ARCHIVO'])
          .apply(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep = False))
          .sum(level=0)
          .rename('DUPLICADOS')
          .reset_index())
9.06 ms ± 437 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
df[df.duplicated(keep = False)].groupby('ARCHIVO').size().rename('DUPLICADOS').reset_index()
4.9 ms ± 1.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


%%timeit
df_1 = df.duplicated(keep=False).groupby(df['ARCHIVO']).sum().rename('DUPLICADOS').reset_index()
4.2 ms ± 134 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

puedes usar groupby en todas las columnas y llamar a size, te adjunto código

```html
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index().\
    rename(columns={0:'DUPLICADOS'})
```

Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo intente. Y me pareció muy útil. Sin embargo no me trae el número de duplicados. Lo que me trae es el número de elementos.

Answer (score 0):

Si te sirve, con esto puedes obnter los registros duplicados:

duplicateRowsDF = df[df.duplicated()]

Y con un nunique puedes obtener el número.

Espero te sirva!!